# Как создать Slash команду Discord.Net.Labs C#

Tags: c#, discord

Использую Discord.Net.Labs. Бот написан на языке C#.
Хочу сделать / команды, как у многих разных ботов, но не смог найти никаких объяснений по тому, как это сделать.

Надеюсь на вашу помощь, так как документация к этому NuGet не очень сильно помогла в создании / команд.

Comment: /command, так??

Comment: Ну чтож вы так невнимательны... Открываем [страницу проекта](https://github.com/Discord-Net-Labs/Discord.Net-Labs), видим там [Guides](https://discord-net-labs.com/guides/introduction/intro.html), ну и там [целый раздел](https://discord-net-labs.com/guides/interactions/application-commands/slash-commands/02-creating-slash-commands.html) посвященный тому, как регистрировать свое в сшел командах сервера дискорда...

Comment: Благодарю. Помогло.